# If-else expressions in Scala are not aligned well in Intellij IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Consider the following function definition...

```
def func(a: Int, b: Int): Int =
  if (a == 0) 1
else .... //not aligned
```

as you can see, the *else* part is not aligned with the *if*. This happens after typing the 1 and pressing the enter key. I have to manually align them myself (move the cursor back to the beginning of the last line and hit the tab key).

Is there a way to make it auto-align?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write this code inside the block {} or use ctrl+alt+l for auto-aligning.
I also prefer to write code in a single line when not using blocks.